# Android Button Alpha looks weird on 2.2 and lower

Tags: android, button, alpha, android-2.2-froyo, android-2.3-gingerbread

Hello stackoverflowers!

This is my button:

```
<Button 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="0.30"
 android:text="@string/menu_button_newgame"
 android:id="@+id/button_newgame" 
/>
```

when I set it's alpha to 150 with

```
button_newgame.getBackground().setAlpha(150);
```

it starts looking weird on 2.2! On 2.3.3 the buttons look normally.

Android 2.3.3: (normal)

[image]

Android 2.2: (buggy)

[image]

What to do ?? :)

Comment: Have you tried enabling dithering? `button_newgame.getBackground().setDither(true)`

Comment: enabling dithering didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the nine-patch.

Try to use

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

All the buttons has the same content and they should keep the same height.

Or try to create a custom nine-patch drawable to use as background.

Comment: It seems like Android 2.2 and lower cuts the button in half horizontally and moves each part above together. As both parts have an alpha of 150, it seems that Android tries to "combine" those alpha, where it overlaps. To solve this, I changed my design a little bit.